# How to run cygwin tmux in cmd.exe

Tags: cmd.exe, cygwin, tmux

I run Cygwin `bash` inside windows command prompt. If I run `tmux` here, it says `open terminal failed: not a terminal`. It runs fine inside `Cygwin Terminal`.
Is there a way to run `tmux` inside windows command prompt?

Comment: Why you need to run it in CMD ?

Comment: cmd is cuter, now we can add alpha to its background colour :)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I have found that works is to install and run SSH server on Cygwin (OpenSSH). Then use `ssh <user>@localhost` in `cmd.exe` (Windows 10 includes the SSH client). `tmux` then should work.

You can install the SSH server by running Cygwin setup then select `openssh` from the packages list.

Then open the Cygwin terminal as admin and run `ssh-host-config -y`. This will install the SSH service. Run the service by typing `net start cygsshd`.

---

Another workaround that is much simpler is to type `screen tmux` (install `screen` if you haven't already). Not sure if there's any limitations by using `tmux` on `screen`.